# Automorphisms and Extensions of Cyclic Groups

Tags: homological-algebra, group-extensions

I can't figure out what question III.4.2  from Hilton & Stammbach's book *A Course in Homological Algebra* is asking:

> Classify the extension classes $[E]$ given by:
>   $$ \mathbb Z_m \rightarrowtail E \twoheadrightarrow  \mathbb Z_n$$
>   under automorphisms of $\mathbb Z_m$ and $\mathbb Z_n$.

My understanding is that, fixing an extension $E$, work out which other extensions appear as those induced by automorphisms of either $\mathbb Z_m$  or $\mathbb Z_n$. However,

1. I am unsure if my understanding is correct,
2. I can't work out an a way to answer the exercise the way I understood it.